# Firebird DB size do not change

Tags: firebird

I'm using the Firebird DB and I did the following. I create a DB, fill it with a lot of records (size of the DB file 113MB). Then I delete all the records but the size remains the same. Is there any way to "shrink" or to "pack" the DB file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The page at [Re: Firebird and vacuum?](http://fb-list-archive.s3-website-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/firebird-support/2007/11/90207.html) claims that you need to use `gbak` to rebuild the database for that.  Note that the file will not grow when you insert records until the total amount of data hits 113MB again, so you might just want to leave the file at that size.

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer. I tested.